# Problema pasar argumento a función postgres

Tags: nodejs, postgresql, api, express

Tengo esta función en el servidor postgres

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_lastdata_id_test(_sensor text)
RETURNS TABLE (id uuid, sid text,ts timestamp without time zone, measure double precision) AS
$func$
SELECT id,sensor_id, date, measure 
FROM measures
WHERE sensor_id = $1
ORDER BY date 
DESC LIMIT 13
$func$  LANGUAGE sql;
```

y una API para obtener los datos desde el servidor postgres

```
app.get('/last/:id', (request, response) => {
  const sid = parseInt(request.params.id)

  pool.query("SELECT * FROM get_lastdata_id_test($1)",[sid], (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error
    }
    response.status(200).json(results.rows)
  })
})
```

Si pruebo la función en el servidor postgres `select * from get_lastdata_id_test('sen-01')` Obtengo lo siguiente:

```
"f2c9fc2d-7ef8-49ee-9b72-a018e12c33a1"  "sen-01"    "2019-08-29 23:59:07"   "1021.57"
"d381cd44-b017-4531-aa23-b4b7bb81138e"  "sen-01"    "2019-08-29 23:55:59"   "1005.95"
"345c8073-edc1-4e4a-9950-1a0bfb661b38"  "sen-01"    "2019-08-29 14:47:31"   "1005.95"
"841e6a43-0756-4ef5-ae77-e8ff3f9a3638"  "sen-01"    "2019-08-29 13:20:16"   "994.23"
"caba2781-ec9a-49e5-a190-72a7fd47b292"  "sen-01"    "2019-08-29 13:16:24"   "988.37"
"99b40219-fb2a-4534-9b49-0a4ecce92cba"  "sen-01"    "2019-08-29 13:08:28"   "984.46"
"d16e805b-3a83-4b87-a414-fe05b03ecfbe"  "sen-01"    "2019-08-29 12:57:30"   "978.6"
"80f0d046-8c43-46bf-9200-dc58465f5163"  "sen-01"    "2019-08-29 12:48:42"   "988.37"
"b6eed4dc-301e-44d4-962b-d7d4b1b6dc8b"  "sen-01"    "2019-08-29 12:44:48"   "998.13"
"15e82547-6b89-41eb-b427-f0659dd0c9e0"  "sen-01"    "2019-08-29 12:36:47"   "990.32"
"735ae26a-78a0-4fe0-af67-9baaa8902f14"  "sen-01"    "2019-08-29 12:32:49"   "992.28"
"cf82c4ad-128d-44a5-8c28-9ac4f552eca5"  "sen-01"    "2019-08-29 12:21:16"   "986.42"
"eafe87ac-9e17-448c-a7e6-ff96e4191243"  "sen-01"    "2019-08-29 12:09:08"   "968.84"
```

Pero usando la url de la API http://localhost:3000/last/sen-01 No obtengo datos:

```
[ ]
```

Cómo puedo pasar correctamente el argumento a la función a través de la URL de la API 'quote'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas enviando un entero como parametro y la funcion segun su definicion recibe un parametro de tipo text

Comment: bueno, cómo soluciono el problema que el parámetro se envíe como string si no puedo usar comillas

Comment: En esta linea: "const sid = parseInt(request.params.id)" estas casteando a entero el parametro que ingresa. Borra el parseInt, es decir la linea quedaria: "const sid = request.params.id"

Comment: Ooooh gracias, tremendo error. I love you :P